# Connecting to other computer using IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

In IIS 6, I was able to right click on the server name and select "connect.." to connect to other remote computer. I know we can do the same in IIS 7 by installing IIS Management Service
After installing IIS7 Management Service, I am still not able to get the Management Service option in my IIS on windows 7.

Thanks,

Nimesh

Comment: This question is better posted on serverfault.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the Remote connect feature is not available on Windows 7.
https://serverfault.com/questions/88050/iis-7-5-on-windows-7-x64-ultimate-is-missing-the-management-service-icon

You need to install this to get it working... http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=32c54c37-7530-4fc0-bd20-177a3e5330b7&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

See these instructions for enabled the Web Management Service:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/158/remote-administration-for-iis-manager/

Comment: mate, I already had that installed, sorry I edited my original question a bit after I posted it originally

Answer (score 0):

Connecting remotely TO a Windows Client is not supported (i.e. connecting to a remote Windows Vista or Windows 7). The Web Management Service is only functional and supported on Server SKU's like Windows Server 2008, or Windows Server 2008 R2.

You can on the other hand connect FROM a client running Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, and Windows 7, but in all these client scenarios you will need to install IIS Manager for Remote Administration support available from: http://www.iis.net/download/IISManager